# Eclipse and Java-9

Tags: java, eclipse

Java-9 was released this week and I installed it instantaneously. Now I want to install eclipse, but during building its dependencies the installer wants to install java-7, which obviously doens't work.

Can anyone help me with this issue? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with the KDE neon windowmanager. Thanks

Comment: Are you installing from the repo or from the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now lets use this method:

1. Install `java 8` (I guess eclipse will accept that):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   ```

   - Check and make sure your default `java 9` is still the boss:

     ```
     sudo update-alternatives --config java
     ```
   - If not modify as need by selecting the number to make default from the previuos step:

     ```
     There are 5 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

     Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
     ------------------------------------------------------------
        0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
        1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
        2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
      * 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode
        4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91                         100       manual mode
        5            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java                100       manual mode

     Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
     ```
2. Now run `sudo update-alternatives --display java` and you should see this:

   ```
   java - manual mode
     link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
     link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
     link java is /usr/bin/java
     slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
      slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
     slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java - priority 1091
   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91 - priority 100
   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java - priority 100
   ```

   - As you can see I use `java 9` as my default but I also have `java 8` installed so **copy the path to to java 8** which is: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java`
3. Now in your eclise folder open `eclipse.ini` file and add these lines to the very top:

   ```
   -vm
   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java
   ```

   - My eclipse.ini file:

     ```
      -vm
      /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java
      -startup
      plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
      --launcher.library
      plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417   
      -product
      org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
      --launcher.defaultAction
      openFile
      -showsplash
      org.eclipse.platform
      --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
      256m
      --launcher.defaultAction
      openFile
      --launcher.appendVmargs
      -vmargs
      -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
      -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
      -Xms256m
      -Xmx1024m
     ```
4. Now launch your eclipse and it will use the given `java vm` in the eclipse.ini file.